Fibration and exact sequences: how to prove that the kernel is contained in the image?
So, we have the usual commutative diagram for the fibration p from E to B.
Let $x_0 \in E$ and consider:
$π_1​(F,x_0​) \overset{j_∗}\to ​π_1(E,x_0​) ​​\overset{p_∗}\to π_1​(B,p(x_0​))$ where
i and j are inclusion maps.
In order to prove this is an exact sequence, I want to prove that the kernel of $p_∗$ is contained in the image of $j_∗$ but I have been stuck at this for hours.

Does this not follow immediately from the homotopy lifting property for fibrations?

I am specifically struggling to see how the lifted homotopy $\tilde{H}(s, 1)$ would be a loop

Isn't $\tilde{H}(s,1): S^1 \to E$ and so a loop by definition?

I can see that $\tilde{H}$ is indeed on the fiber F = $p^{-1}p(x_0)$ but I cannot see how that immediately implies it is a loop. I might be missing something trivial here...

@Sharon You are lifting a homotopy of the form $H\colon S^1 \times I \to B$, so $\bar{H}({{-}}, 1)$ is a map of the form $S^1 \to E$, i.e. a loop in $E$.

Let $[\gamma] \in \pi_1(E, x_0)$ be a class such that $p_*([\gamma]) = 0$, i.e. $p \circ \gamma$ is nullhomotopic. Let $H\colon S^1 \times I \to B$ be a homotopy contracting $p \circ \gamma$. We then have a lifting problem
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    S^1 \times \{0\} @>\gamma >> E \\
    @VVV @VVp V \\ 
    S^1 \times I @>>H > B
\end{CD}
so we obtain a lift $\tilde{H}\colon S^1 \times I \to E$ lifting $H$.
At time 0 this is $\gamma$ and at time 1 it is contained in $F = p^{-1}(p(x_0))$ since $H({{-}}, 1) = \mathrm{const}_{p(x_0)}$, so $[\gamma]$ is represented by the loop $\tilde{H}({{-}}, 1)\colon S^1 \to F$ and therefore in the image of $j_*$.
